# Windows Server requires login after reboot

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2, and after it reboots I absolutely need to connect to it in local or else it will not allow any connections (RDP, shared folders).

What is the option (local or group policy) to allow connection without needing one to connect to it in person.

Comment: Is this a VM or a physical server?

Comment: It is a physical server.

Comment: `What is the option (local or group policy) to allow connection without needing one to connect to it in person` - There isn't one. There's something wrong with your server. It shouldn't require you to log on locally in order to connect to it remotely. I suspect a problem with the NIC or NIC driver.

Comment: But after you have connected to it, then it will accept RDP sessions?

Comment: Yep after the login it works. I think, like the previous comment, it seems to be my NIC not going up for some reason, I see it with a interjection sign prior to login in. Any idea on that? I can't see why it doesn't go up since after the login...it goes up.